# What does "pill" mean here?

Tags: meaning, metaphors, rhetoric

https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/why-you-should-give-it-a-try#id1337 says:

> Just as with pills, I'll try to be as short as possible.

What does "pill" mean here?

Is it a metaphor for something short?

Comment: I think it must be. It is not (in my experience) a recognised use, and looking at that page, I didn't understand the title "Nix pills"

Comment: At the bottom of the page you linked to is a [hotspot link](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/pr01) called "Nix Pills", which takes you to a page that starts with ***Preface** This is a ported version of the **Nix Pills, a series of blog posts** written by Luca Bruno (aka Lethalman) and orginally published in 2014 and 2015. It provides **a tutorial introduction into the Nix package manager** and Nixpkgs package collection, **in the form of short chapters called 'pills'.*** It's a bit of a "one-off" usage - the standard metaphoric usage here is ***bite-sized*** chunks / sections / chapters...

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the context. The whole article is about "Nix Pills". The writer is saying that just as "Nix pills" are short, so his explanations will be short.

Comment: Thanks. pills are small. How are they short?

Comment: To be short means to be small in length. I didn't read the whole article to understand exactly what "Nix pills" are, but apparently some small pieces of Nix. Maybe the analogy is a bit strained going from "small in size" to "short in length", but the meaning is clear enough. Every analogy is imperfect or it wouldn't be an analogy, it would be the same thing.

Comment: @Tim - they are swallowed in one gulp, which may be more relevant when understanding the usage.

Comment: As well as pills, you can find 'bite-sized chunks'.

Comment: @Tim Your question is like asking how a bird's tweets can be limited to 4000 characters.